# For the density $f(x\mid \theta)=\theta x^{\theta-1}$, is $\sum x_i$ sufficient for $\theta$?

Tags: probability, statistical-inference

> Suppose $x_1$, ..., $x_n$ be a random sample of distribution with pdf: $$f(x\mid \theta)=\theta x^{\theta-1}\mathbf1_{0<x<1},\,θ>0$$
>
> Is $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ a sufficient statistic?

My classmate used the factorization theorem to prove that $\prod_{i=1}^nx_i$ is a sufficient statistic. Thus, $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ is not a sufficient statistic.

But I remembered that the sufficient statistics can be more than one. So to prove that $\sum_ix_i$ is not a sufficient statistic, we may need to prove that $\sum_ix_i$ can not be a function of the minimal sufficient statistic.

It seems that it is too complex to prove this. Proving by definition may be easier. But I don't know how to calculate $f(x\mid \sum _ix_i,\theta)$.

Am I wrong? Can we use the factorization theorem to prove? Will it be easy to prove by definition? If yes, then how to calculate $f(x\mid \sum _ix_i,\theta)$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Concentrating just on your last Q, and with no comment on whether this is the best way to go - recall that if $U, V$ are independent and have densities $f_U, f_V,$ then the density of $U+V$ is $f_U * f_V,$ where $*$ is the convolution operator. So, you can compute $f(\sum_{i \le n} x_i; \theta),$ using [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7Bx+%3D+0%7D%5Ea+x%5Es+(a+-+x)%5Et+dx) and some induction to find that it is $\frac{(\Gamma(\theta) \theta)^n}{\Gamma(n\theta)} (\sum x_i) ^{n\theta - 1}.$ Now write down the joint dist. of $\{x_i\}, \sum x_i,$ and use Bayes' rule.

Comment: @stochasticboy321: Thanks for your reply!!!! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: $X \sim \mathsf{Beta}(2,1):$ suggest you see [_this page_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Maximum_likelihood) and look under maximum likelihood estimation.

Comment: To prove that a statistic is *not* sufficient, one usually has to use the definition of sufficiency. Here $X\sim \text{Beta}(\theta,1)$ and certainly $\prod X_i$ or $\ln \prod X_i=\sum \ln X_i$ is sufficient for $\theta$. The latter is a minimal complete sufficient statistic. As far as I can tell, $\sum X_i$ is not a one-to-one function of $\sum \ln X_i$.